# Sequelize won't update model

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a simple user model with two simple associations:

```
export const Password = sequelize.define("password", {
    hash: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    salt: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
});

export const User = sequelize.define("user", {
    firstname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue: ''
    },
    lastname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue: ''
    },
})

export const Email = sequelize.define("email", {
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    },
    verified: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false
    },
    verificationCode:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
})

Email.User = Email.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
User.Email = User.hasOne(Email, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: 'CASCADE'})

Password.User = Password.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
User.Password = User.hasOne(Password, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
```

Inside my database i have one model persisted which i can fetch easily with:

```
static async getUserByEmail(email){
        return User.findOne({
            where: {'$email.email$': {[Op.eq]: email}},
            include: [{model: Email, as: 'email'},{model: Password, as: 'password'}]
        })
    }
```

The result, as expected is the user model with the created association. When i debug i can see it all clearly.

[image: User model]

Now i just want to update any association. I cant figure this out to save my life.

```
const user = await UserDAO.getUserByEmail('test@test.at')

user.set({password:{hash: 'i am changed now'}})

const updatedUser = await user.save()
```

After the `user.set({password:{hash: 'i am changed now'}})` method the debugger shows the updated model

[image: Updated model]

**Note** the password.hash is the desired value.

And also after i have called the save method, the returned object indicates the change.

[image: updated model]

**However there just is no update happening inside the database**

I have also tried

```
const user = await UserDAO.getUserByEmail('test@test.at')

user.password.set({hash: 'i am changed now'})

await user.save()
```

and

```
const user = await UserDAO.getUserByEmail('test@test.at')

user.password.hash = 'i am changed now'

await user.save()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `await user.setPassword({hash: 'i am changed now'})`?

Comment: No ! When i use it it throws `Uncaught SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: password.userId cannot be null`

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Try `await user.password.update({hash: 'i am changed now'})`

Comment: I really have no clue what going on. When i use `user.password.hash = 'i am changed now'` i can even see the previous data value inside the object. Sequelize seems to exactly know what i want to do. There just does not happen any actual SQL in the end....

Comment: I suppose Sequelize can't save an associated model by calling a parent model `save`

Comment: From official documentation: "This method is not aware of eager loaded associations. In other words, if some other model instance (child) was eager loaded with this instance (parent), and you change something in the child, calling save() will simply ignore the change that happened on the child."

Comment: The implementation really lacks this feature.... The model instance literally recognizes the previous and current value of the associations. Why would a save command on the root ignore the changes ?? Does this mean when i update several associations, i have to call save() on EVERY association object ? Not only on root ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `save` on `password` because Sequelize is not aware of changes in associated model instances.

```js
const user = await UserDAO.getUserByEmail('test@test.at')

user.password.set({hash: 'i am changed now'})

await user.password.save()
```

> This method is not aware of eager loaded associations. In other words, if some other model instance (child) was eager loaded with this instance (parent), and you change something in the child, calling save() will simply ignore the change that happened on the child

See [the instance method "save"](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#instance-method-save)